# Convert SQL to Doctrine 2 DQL with non associative join

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I need convert this SQL to DQL. Here exists entity Log that I wish to group by remoteAddress and then attach the same entity for details.

```
    $q="SELECT qnt.*, log.*
        FROM
            (SELECT COUNT(log.remote_address) cnt, remote_address, site_id
            FROM analytics_log log
            WHERE log.site_id = 6
            GROUP BY log.remote_address
            HAVING cnt >= 2
            ORDER BY cnt DESC) qnt
        LEFT JOIN (analytics_log log) USING (remote_address)
        ORDER BY qnt.cnt DESC, log.time ASC
    ";
```

I have created query for inner select. It is

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('log loga, COUNT(log.remoteAddress) cnt')
       ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'log')
       //error: 'log2 WITH log2.remoteAddress': Error: Class Analytics\Entity\Log has no association named remoteAddress
       //->leftJoin('log.remoteAddress', 'log2', 'WITH', 'log2.remoteAddress == log.remoteAddress') // this not working
       ->where('log.id >= :id')
       ->andWhere('log.isPaidClick = :paidEngine')
       //->andWhere('log.site = 6')
       ->groupBy('log.remoteAddress')
       ->having('cnt >= :threshold')
       ->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')
    ;
```

Comment: If you know how to add join without association into entity this will be enough.

Comment: a quick hack for your  query will be create a view for your query and then generate its entity